# Using grub, is it possible to use "if, while" during booting (before loading normal.mod)?

Tags: grub

My computer has grub installed. During booting before normal.mod is loaded, I need to be able to run if and while commands in my config file which has been linked into core.img (using grub-mkimage -c myconfig.confg). In myconfig.config, I have an if statement and I kept getting "unknown command if" during booting.  I saw an example in http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/Embedded-configuration.html and looks like I just need to include search, test, and normal modules.  Am I missing something?  Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether this is a bug or the documentation is lacking information.

Anyway there is a **workaround** by putting your config file in a memdisk image which you can append to the core.img. The config file can then be executed - including scripting support - via `configfile`:

Create a tarball formatted memdisk image including your config file:

```
tar -cf memdisk.tar myconfig.config
```

Create `early.cfg`: (which will serve to execute `myconfig.config` via `configfile`):

```
configfile (memdisk)/myconfig.config
```

Create `core.img`: (note that you will need the additional modules `memdisk tar configfile`)

```
grub-mkimage -c early.cfg -m memdisk.tar -o core.img search test normal memdisk tar configfile
```

Comment: It's not really a bug: the `-c` config runs in rescue mode with limited commands available. GRUB normally enters `normal` mode at the end of that file. https://help-grub.gnu.narkive.com/SgdiBpll/using-conditionals-in-embedded-config For the same reason, you can't have menus in the `-c`  embedded config. That last bit is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: Oh, and not even comments work in the `-c` embedded file: it prints syntax error for `#`.

Comment: BTW, it seems not possible to enter `normal` mode without loading some (external) fille. That's because `normal` without any argument it loads the default `${prefix}/grub.cfg`. I'm not sure what happens if the file can't be loaded, but I guess it kicks back to rescue mode.

Comment: Actually, in that last case, it doesn't drop you to a rescue prompt, but to a normal prompt (assuming `normal` is included in `core.img`) . Still not useful for scripting anything.